# If the homeomorphism has the non-negative or non-positive determinant?

Tags: calculus, general-topology, analysis

Let $ \Omega_1 $ and $ \Omega_2 $ be domains(open and connected) in $ \mathbb{R}^2 $. $ \psi:\Omega_1\to\mathbb{R} $ and $ \phi:\Omega_1\to\mathbb{R} $ are $ C^1 $ functions with two variables. Moreover, we assume that map $ (x,y)\to (\phi(x,y),\psi(x,y)) $ is homeomorphism from $ \Omega_1 $ to $ \Omega_2 $, i.e. the map $ (x,y)\to (\phi(x,y),\psi(x,y)) $ is continuous from $ \Omega_1 $ to $ \Omega_2 $ and has continuous inverse map. I want to ask that if I can obtain that the Jacobi determunant of the map, denoted as $ \frac{\partial(\phi,\psi)}{\partial(x,y)} $ is either non-positive or non-negative in $ \Omega_1 $, i.e. either $ \frac{\partial(\phi,\psi)}{\partial(x,y)}\geq 0 $ for all $ (x,y)\in\Omega_1 $,  or $ \frac{\partial(\phi,\psi)}{\partial(x,y)}\leq 0 $ for all $ (x,y)\in\Omega_1 $, . I have tried by considering the image sets of a curve in $ \Omega_1 $ and by using the connectness of $ \Omega_1 $ but failed. Can you give me some references or hints?

Comment: @Glare, I have mentioned that the function $ \phi $ ana $ \psi $ are $ C^1 $ functions. This assumption gives that the Jacobian determinant exists and is continuous.

Comment: I somehow missed that. Will delete my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote our $C^1$ homeomorphism by $F(x):=(\phi(x),\psi(x))$, for $x\in \Omega_1 \subset \mathbb R^2$.
(Higher dimension is possible, with the same proof.)

Let $D(x)$ denote the derivative of $F$ at $x$.
Let $J(x)$ denote the Jacobian determinant of $F$ at $x$.
Thus $D(x)$ is a linear map of $\mathbb R^2$ into $\mathbb R^2$ and
$J(x)$ is the determinant of the matrix that represents $D(x)$.

$B(x,\varepsilon)$ denotes a closed ball (disk) centered at $x$ of radius $\varepsilon$.

**Let $x_1, x_2 \in \Omega_1$ be some points with $J(x_1)>0$, $J(x_2)<0$.**
We will show that this assumption leads to a **contradiction.**

As $J(x_1)>0$, the linear map $D(x_1)$ is invertible; denote by $m_1$ the norm of the inverse mapping. Then
$\| D(x_1)(x-x_1) \| \ge (1/m_1) \| x-x_1 \|$ for every $x\in \mathbb R^2$.

As $D(x_1)$ is the derivative of $F$ at $x_1$, there is $\varepsilon_1>0$
such that $F(.)$ is well approximated by the affine map $$F(x_1) + D(x_1)( . - x_1)$$ in $B_1:=B(x_1,\varepsilon_1) \subset \Omega_1$ in the following sense: For every $x\in B_1$, $$\| F(x) - F(x_1) - D(x_1)(x-x_1)\| <
(1/m_1) \| x-x_1 \| \le  \| D(x_1)(x-x_1) \|. \tag{*}$$
We will use this for the boundary points of $B_1$, which is a circle around $x_1$.
The image of this circle will "topologically be a circle around $F(x_1)$".

Let $\varphi_1(t) = x_1 + ( \varepsilon_1  \sin t, \varepsilon_1  \cos t)$, $t\in [0,2\pi]$. In the following, we always consider all $t\in [0,2\pi]$.
Let $s_0(t)=F(x_1) + D(x_1)( \varphi_1(t) - x_1 )$ and
$s_1(t) = F(\varphi(t))$.
For $h\in [0,1]$, let $s_h(t)$ be the linear combination of $s_0(t)$ and $s_1(t)$, i.e., $s_h(t) = (1-h)s_0(t) + h s_1(t)$.

If $s$ is curve and $y$ is a point, denote $I(s,y)$ the index of $y$ with respect to $s$. The *index* is sometimes called *[winding number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number#Topology)* and it is special case of more general notion of the *degree*.

Obviously $I(\varphi, x_1) = 1$. The image $s_0$ of the circle $\varphi$ by
the linear map is an ellipse centred at $F(x_1)$ and the index
$I(s_0, F(x_1))$ is plus or minus one, depending on the determinant.
As $J(x_1)>0$, we have $I(s_0, F(x_1))=1$. As $h\mapsto s_h$
is a homotopy of $s_0$ and $s_1$, and by (*), $s_h$ always misses $F(x_1)$,
we have $I(s_1, F(x_1)) = I(s_0, F(x_1))=1$ because the [degree is homotopy invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_continuous_mapping#Properties).

We can carry out the same construction at $x_2$ to obtain
$\varepsilon_2>0$,
$\varphi_2(t) = x_2 + ( \varepsilon_2  \sin t, \varepsilon_2  \cos t)$, (where still $t\in [0,2\pi]$),
$s_2(t) = F(\varphi_2(t))$
such that $I(s_2, F(x_2)) = -1$. The minus sign comes from the the fact that $J(x_2)<0$.

Now, we construct a homotopy of $s_1$ and $s_2$.
For $h\in [0,1]$, let $\varphi_{1+h}(t) = (1-h) \varphi_1(t) + h \varphi_2(t)$
and $s_{1+h}(t) = F(\varphi_{1+h})(t)$.
The curve $\varphi_{1+h}$ is a circle with a positive radius $(1-h)\varepsilon_1+h\varepsilon_2$
and center $x_{1+h} = (1-h) x_1 + h x_2$.

As $F$ is injective, the curve $s_{1+h}$ misses $F(x_{1+h})$.

As the index is homotopy invariant we have
$-1 = I(s_2, F(x_2))  =  I(s_1, F(x_1))  = 1 $ which is a contradiction.

So it impossible that the Jacobian of a $C^1$ homeomorphism changes the sing.

I suppose this should be known --- **please** tell me where it is in the literature.

Comment: 1/2 Attemprt for a short intuitive presentation: Take $x_1$, $x_2$ with different signs (plus and minus) of the Jacobian. As the derivative at $x_i$ exists, the functions behaves like a linear function near $x_i$. Take a small circle $C_i$ at $x_i$ parametrised in the counter clock wise direction. The image under $F$ of $C_i$ is approximately a circle, the parametrisation runs counter clock wise for $i=1$ and clockwise for $i=2$.

Comment: 2/2 Now consider continuous moving circle, starting in the position of $C_1$ and ending in $C_2$. The shape of the  image at each moment is possibly very different from a circle, but topologically it simply winds about the 'centre' some number of times - this number cannot change because the movement is continuous. But we start at +1 and end with -1, which is a contraditcion.

Comment: Asking the [right question](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Can+jacobian+of+homeomorphism+change+the+sign%3F&t=ffab&ia=web) leads quickly to an [answer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-019-1554-8), [and more](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~rokyta/preprint/2009-pap/2009-307.pdf). I should have done that at the start.